# How to configure SSL in my Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, ssl

we developed an application in Laravel and hosted on Heroku, configured the Domain and now we are having difficulty configuring SSL. We have already hired the Passatempo plan to test and it is still appearing unsafe on our website. :( What settings can be made to solve this problem ?????? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO.. do u have `ssh` control .? and what OS server?

Answer (score 0):

If you want SSL Cloudflare provides it for free and if you want an end to end encryption  with Cloudflare recommend you to check out [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/)